# First Listview get updated with notifyDataSetChanged() Second ListView wont update

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I've got two ListViews in my (tabhost) Android application. Both with a custom BaseAdapter. Both ListViews are requesting a JSON stream. When the JSON stream is loaded the custom BaseAdapter is calling notifyDataSetChanged.

When i select one of the tabs with the ListView the List gets loaded perfectly, when i select the other tab with the other list in it, the list is not loading. In which order i select the tabs does not matter. When i select tab1, tab1 gets loaded, and tab2 will fail to load the list. When i select tab 2 first, the list for tab2 will load, when i select tab1, this list will fail.

This method is called in the custom BaseAdapter when the JSON stream is loaded:

```
@Override
public void jsonObjectLoaded(JSONObject a) {


        setItems((JSONArray) a.get("categories"));
        for(int c = 0; c<getItems().size(); c++)
            imgs.add(null);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The getView() method is called the first time on the first selected tab, it wont get called on the second selected tab. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can u put the code of the custom baseadapter and also the part where you are setting the adapters to the listviews.